# Command line portable application

Tags: python, user-interface, command-line, console

Not sure if this is the location to ask this, so please close or move as appropriate.

We are bundling Python2.7 64-bit and a number of python libraries (GDAL, SciPy, Numpy) into an application (py2app / pyinstaller).  I wonder if it is possible to create a stand alone terminal that has access to the installed libraries, but not the system libraries.  This would be akin to [FWTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/).

The goal is to allow the user to open a command prompt within the GUI and have access to all of the libraries within the application a la a virtual environment.

For example, a user with GDAL 1.8 installed could download this application, launch a stand alone command line and utilize our build of gdal 1.9.1 from within the application.

Any references would be appreciated as we are just considering this approach and are unsure of the feasibility.

We are writing this in python.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a very easy way to embed a console / terminal into any of the GUI frameworks. The closest I've heard of is PyGTK's VteTerminal. You might be able to use Python's curses library, but I haven't been able to find any good ways to wrap that in a GUI either.

If all you want is a Python shell, you might be able to use wxPython's PyShell or PyCrust widgets. Those are pretty straight-forward.